# How to set TCP Keepalive in Reactor Netty HTTP client?

Tags: kotlin, netty, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I saw that

```
HttpClient.from(TcpClient.create().option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true))
```

`from` method was deprecated.

How currently am I supposed to set `SO_KEEPALIVE` using `HttpClient.create()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was easier that I thought:

```
HttpClient.create().option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
```